# Why my php code turns to comment?

Tags: php, html

im tried to write php to my html file, im using wampserver, but when i add php in html it's turns to comment why ? Pls help.

```
<?php 
echo "hello"

 ?>
```

**turns to comment**

```
<--?php 
echo "hello"

 ?-->
```

Comment: no its .html is it should phtml ? im new in php

Comment: It should be `.php` but your web server doesn't support `php`.

Comment: but i want it in html code

Comment: It should be a .php file. Your php file can have html too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add PHP code to an HTML file.

If the file has PHP code then the file needs to have a valid PHP extension, such as `.php` for example. The PHP file can contain HTML code also.